# UITabbarController in UiSplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am new to ipad development. I am developing an ipad application similar to the following apps:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dropbox/id327630330?mt=8

http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/box.net/id290853822?mt=8...

In both these apps structure looks like uitabbarcontroller integrated inside uisplitviewcontroller. But i ve heard that uisplitviewcontroller cannot be a rootviewcontroller. Then how these apps designed??? How to do a structure like that???

Comment: where's the uisplitview in these apps?

Comment: It looks like splitview structure only... Master view contains tab control and detail view displays file.... Isn't it????

Comment: oh..I was looking at the iPhone pics.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that uisplitviewcontroller cannot be a rootviewcontroller. So, it has to be added as a subview as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options {
UIViewController *vc1 = [[CalculatorViewController alloc] init]; 
UIViewController *vc2 = [[GraphViewController alloc] init];
UISplitViewController*svc=[[UISplitViewControlleralloc]init];
svc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil];
[vc1 release];  [vc2 release];
[window addSubview:svc.view]; 
[window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
return YES;}
```

Check out this [sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html) available at developer.apple.com

Comment: Yes i have checked that sample.. But my question is how can i create tabbarcontroller in master view controller of splitview?

Comment: It should'nt be difficult...I made some changes to the apple sample:- http://cl.ly/3P12322C0U0Q3p2A3R39.  It's looking weird now but give it time and you'll have a good looking app...

Comment: NOTE: split view is shown in landscape only. In portrait, you'll have a popover view only.

Comment: Your code did most of the things with some issues.. But i cant follow it fully since i m a newbie :( Anyway i ll go through it and try by myself...

Comment: ya...I only made some make-shift changes to depict how it can be done. Put some effort into it and you'll have an app that will look quite like the ones you've mentioned. Good luck :)

Comment: I was unable to do it... More am changing the code the output goes more weird :( Thinking of changing my structure :)

Comment: Finally i got it... It is much easier than i thought... Please check this whether its the right way to do it... http://www.cx.com/dl/?sn=869e4207d064...

Comment: Hey i stuck with one more problem... How can i change detail view if tab changes in master view??? Could u help me???